# When I copy a VS2017 project, size of copied directory doubles

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am following an online C++ tutorial for Visual Studio 2017 and I thought it would be smart to copy the entire project directory each video, in case I need a fallback. However, I noticed that the size of each copy I work from roughly doubles each time I do this (NOT including size increase from appending new files).

Example: I have 13 copies of the same project. Project02 is a copy of Project01; Project03 is a copy of Project02; ...Project13 is a copy of Project12. Each time I make some changes, of course. Here's the weird part:

Project01 is less than 15 MB.
Project13 is 2.04 GB.
If I create a new empty project and dump the header and cpp files into it, confirming that it works, the size of the project is only 125 MB.

What causes this inflation? How can I avoid it? Can I fix it?

Comment: Intermediate build files, IntelliSense database, precompiled header files, mostly.  Hard to see, the ".vs" subdirectory of a project is hidden.  VS was designed with the hard assumption that programmers use source control instead of backup copies.

Comment: If I delete that will .vs will it regenerate smaller? Because again, if I just copy-paste-import the code into an empty project, that project is about 90% smaller.

Comment: Focus on the important stuff, github.com lets you create an account for free.

Comment: As mentioned by Hans, use a source code management system. Git or TFS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Source Control:**

VS 2017 has an option to link to GitHub or Azure repositories. Assuming you have a Github account:

1. Go online to your Github account and sign in. Create a new repository. (ALT: do it through the command line. Don't know how? Me neither.
2. with your existing project open, there is an option in the bottom-right corner of the screen, on a blue bar, that says "Add to Source Control". Click that.
3. The Project panel will switch to a new set of menu options for Source control. You will want to "push" the project to an existing repository. On the github webpage, when you created the new repo, you will have been given a link. copy that link:
   [image]

   and paste it in the field here:

   [image]
4. The reason to use "Source Control" is that VS2017 will know better than to duplicate unneeded files for different branches. You can create new branches directly on Github.com, via the command line, or in this menu:

   [image]

You can watch a video walkthrough of how to access Source Control here:

[**video tutorial for linking Github repo with VS 2017**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jUiuIAZt6Dw)

**Quick-and-Dirty Way:**

Now let's say the stakes are low and you just want to jam-out some tutorials without creating accounts or repos. You can just copy-paste the project folder, rename it, **delete the hidden .vs folder**, and compile the copied project. In my example, the size of the copied and modified project shrank from just over **2 GB** down to **24 MB** (this is after about a dozen copies without doing this). And the job was done in under a minute. Doing this will make you *[**worse than Hitler**](https://youtu.be/OtMpRjX2hZY?t=67)* though.

[image]

Deleting the .vs folder may also put your compiler back to default settings. In my case, I had to change the compiler settings for the copied project from x64 back to x86 (this is a dropdown list at the top of the screen).

Comment: The way to *make VS2017 do this for you* is to stop manually copying your projects and use version control instead. If you insist on doing things the wrong way, [it's not a VS problem](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/PEBKAC).

Comment: It's just a school project, man. I only learned what "source control" is in the last hour. You were right, I just didn't know what you were talking about and had a hard time looking it up, so I did what I could.